# Spring boot 2 yaml property work but highlights in IDE

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml

I have yaml config in my Spring boot app with my properties:

```
#app configs
my.messages.max_count: 5
my.messages.delay: 100
my.schedulers.charge_delay: 5000
```

It work but IntellijIDE highlights this lines and say:

```
Cannot resolve configuration property 'my.schedulers.charge_delay' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Checks Spring Boot application .yaml configuration files. Highlights unresolved and deprecated configuration keys and invalid values. Works only for Spring Boot 1.2 or higher
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: See  [Configuration Metadata](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html) in Spring boot reference. Especially [Generating Your Own Metadata](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor)

Comment: This is the correct way but it seems that it get be tricky to make this work in IDEA.. I also followed the procedure here : http://www.mdoninger.de/2015/05/16/completion-for-custom-properties-in-spring-boot.html , then I managed to get the descriptor "spring-configuration-metadata.json" generated under /build/classes/java/main/META_INF/  directory.    But then you have to copy this file into the source directory ( src/main/resources/META-INF) so that IDEA can parse it and resolve properties from the yaml file.

Comment: This can also help  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483697/re-run-spring-boot-configuration-annotation-processor-to-update-generated-metada

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
my:
 messages:
  max_count: 5
  delay: 100
  charge_delay: 5000
```

....
....

you are not using the yml syntax.

EDIT:

You can write your own Config class like this:

Config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my")
public class YamlConfig {

 private String delay;

 public String getDelay() {
     return url;
 }

 public void setDelay(String delay) {
     this.delay = delay;
 }
}
```

pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

yml:

```
my:
 delay: 5
```

best regards

Comment: because it does not solve the problem. you can try it. My example does not match the yamle format, yes, but if I rewrite it to yaml format - it not solve the problem.

Comment: ok now I understood. I've edit my post. I hope this will help you