# Intellij IDEA not generate spring-configuration-metadata-json

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, properties

I wait that IntelliJ IDEA generates `spring-configuration-metadata-json` for me.
But it doesn't happen. I read [this](http://www.mdoninger.de/2015/05/16/completion-for-custom-properties-in-spring-boot.html) and [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor) articles and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33599838/4781349) and I create a simple `spring-boot` application:

Gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.4.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
}
```

Property:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(value = "test")
public class MyProperties {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    //getters setters
```

I try to build, rebuild, compile... But IDEA not create this metadata for me. What do I do wrong?